# Как в lazarus в Linux подключить файл .so к проекту

Tags: lazarus, so

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  Classes
  { you can add units after this };

function ret_num():integer; cdecl;
begin
  Result := 2;
end;

exports ret_num;

begin
end.
```

как сделать что б я мог вызвать функцию ret_num в другой прогремме. Вот так выдает ошибку.

````
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation


{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }
function ret1 () :integer; cdecl; external 'libGUMod.so';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(ret1()));
end;

end.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Имя функции в модуле (ret1) должно совпадать с именем вызываемой функции из библиотеки (ret_num):
function ret_num () :integer; cdecl; external 'libGUMod.so';

Либо в библиотеке указать псевдоним функции:
exports ret_num name 'ret1';